# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]

Tags: bibliographies

I don't know why but everything is fine and when i add my bibliography i get this error. Any ideas ?

MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\allowdisplaybreaks[4]
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=1.5cm}
\topmargin0.0cm
\headheight0.0cm
\headsep0.0cm
\oddsidemargin0.0cm
\textheight23.0cm
\textwidth16.5cm
\footskip1.0cm
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\swappedhead{~}{.~}{}{}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}
\swapnumbers
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Théorème}[subsection]
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{coro}[thm]{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemme}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{mydef}[thm]{Définition}
\newtheorem{exe}[thm]{Exemple}
\newtheorem{exes}[thm]{Exemples}
\newtheorem{req}[thm]{}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushright}
\textbf{ANNÉE 2017}
\end{flushright}~\\
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{rennes.png}~\\~\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ENS-Rennes.png}
\end{center}
~\\
\begin{center}
{\Large \textbf{RAPPORT DE STAGE}}\\
\begin{center}
{\large par}
\end{center}
{\Large \textbf{Pierre Houédry}}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\rule{14cm}{0.2pt}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
~\\
~\\
\begin{tabular}{lll}
{\huge \textbf{Travail autour de}} &  &{\large  sous la tutelle de} \\
                   &  & {\Large \textbf{Jerôme Poineau } }     \\
{\huge \textbf{la conjecture de Schanuel}}      &  &                   
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\section{Autour de la conjecture de Schanuel}
\subsection{Résultats préliminaires}

\begin{prop}
Soit $C \subset E \subset F$ des corps et $\Delta$ un ensemble de dérivations de F avec $\bigcap_{D \in \Delta} ker(D) = C$ et $D(E) \subset E$ pour $D \in \Delta$. Alors l'application canonique
\begin{center}
$\displaystyle \beta : F \otimes_C \cap_{D \in \Delta} ker(D^1) \longrightarrow \Omega_{F/E}$,
\end{center}
telle que $\beta(f \otimes w)= fw$, est injective. 
\end{prop}

On a bien existence de $D^1$ pour chaque $D \in \Delta$ car $D(E) \subset E$ ce qui nous permet d'utiliser la propriété précédente. L'application $\beta $ est bien définie car $\Omega_{F/C}$ est un F-module et $D^1$ une dérivation sur $\Omega_{F/C}$ donc $ker(D^1) \subset \Omega_{F/C}$ donc $fw \in \Omega_{F/C}$.
\begin{proof}
Par l'absurde supposons qu'il existe $w_1,...,w_m \in \cap_{D \in \Delta} ker(D^1)$ et $f_1,...,f_m \in F$ non tous nuls tels que 
\begin{center}
$(*)$ ~~~~ $\displaystyle \sum\limits^m_{i=1}f_iw_i =0 $.      
\end{center}
On peut supposer que $m$ est la longueur minimale d'une telle relation et que $f_1=1$, on montrera que $\forall i, ~f_i \in C$. On peut alors appliquer $D^1$ pour $D \in \Delta$ à $(*)$, ce qui nous donne
\begin{center}
$0 = \sum\limits^m_{i=1} D(f_i)w_i+f_iD^1(w_i) = \sum\limits^m_{i=2} D(f_i)w_i$.
\end{center}
Par minimalité de la longueur de la relation on doit avoir $D(f_i)=0, ~\forall D \in \Delta$, c'est-à-dire $f_i \in C,~\forall i$. Cela permet de conclure. En effet, on a
\begin{center}
$\displaystyle \sum\limits^m_{i=1} f_i \otimes_C w_i =  \sum\limits^m_{i=1} 1 \otimes_C f_i w_i = 1 \otimes_C  \sum\limits^m_{i=1} f_i w_i = 0 $.
\end{center}
\end{proof}



\newpage
\nocite{*}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mabiblio}
\end{document}
```

The bib file

```
@Article{,
author = {James Ax},
title = {On Schanuel's Conjectures},
journal = {Annals of Mathematics},
year = {1971},
volume = {93},
pages = {252-268},
}

@Book{,
title = {Corps commutatifs et thoérie de Galois},
publisher = {Calvage \& Mounet},
year = {2008},
}

@Book{,
title = {Algèbre corporelle},
chapter = {6},
publisher = {},
year = {},
pages = {139-164},
}
@Book{,
title = {Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves},
publisher = {},
year = {},
}

@Book{,
title = {Introduction to commutative algebra},
chapter = {2},
publisher = {},
year = {},
}
@Book{,
title = {Commutative Algebra},
chapter = {26},
publisher = {},
year = {},
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is too generic for even trying and find some clue.

Comment: I should put all my document here ?

Comment: No: you should try and extract a minimal example showing the problem.

Comment: I just edit my post ! :)

Comment: This doesn't produce errors.

Comment: Hmmm... do you think it can come from my bibtex file ? cause for me it give the error.

Comment: That's indeed likely

Comment: I edit the post and put the biblio so ! Thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you *really* have `•` in the bibliographic entries?

Comment: For me it was like a blank.

Comment: @Pierre21 While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Just change the MWE of the bib file

Comment: This is what @samcarter meant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

Your bibliography entries should have labels.  Once I've added those and added a first line to your latex file, everything runs fine and produces the expected result.  I have made no attempt at sanitizing your latex code to produce a MWE.

```
\providecommand{\pgfsyspdfmark}[3]{}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\allowdisplaybreaks[4]
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=1.5cm}
\topmargin0.0cm
\headheight0.0cm
\headsep0.0cm
\oddsidemargin0.0cm
\textheight23.0cm
\textwidth16.5cm
\footskip1.0cm
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\swappedhead{~}{.~}{}{}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}
\swapnumbers
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Théorème}[subsection]
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{coro}[thm]{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemme}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{mydef}[thm]{Définition}
\newtheorem{exe}[thm]{Exemple}
\newtheorem{exes}[thm]{Exemples}
\newtheorem{req}[thm]{}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushright}
\textbf{ANNÉE 2017}a
\end{flushright}~\\
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}~\\~\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-b}
\end{center}
~\\
\begin{center}
{\Large \textbf{RAPPORT DE STAGE}}\\
\begin{center}
{\large par}
\end{center}
{\Large \textbf{Pierre Houédry}}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\rule{14cm}{0.2pt}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
~\\
~\\
\begin{tabular}{lll}
{\huge \textbf{Travail autour de}} &  &{\large  sous la tutelle de} \\
                   &  & {\Large \textbf{Jerôme Poineau } }     \\
{\huge \textbf{la conjecture de Schanuel}}      &  &                   
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\section{Autour de la conjecture de Schanuel}
\subsection{Résultats préliminaires}

\begin{prop}
Soit $C \subset E \subset F$ des corps et $\Delta$ un ensemble de dérivations de F avec $\bigcap_{D \in \Delta} ker(D) = C$ et $D(E) \subset E$ pour $D \in \Delta$. Alors l'application canonique
\begin{center}
$\displaystyle \beta : F \otimes_C \cap_{D \in \Delta} ker(D^1) \longrightarrow \Omega_{F/E}$,
\end{center}
telle que $\beta(f \otimes w)= fw$, est injective. 
\end{prop}

On a bien existence de $D^1$ pour chaque $D \in \Delta$ car $D(E) \subset E$ ce qui nous permet d'utiliser la propriété précédente. L'application $\beta $ est bien définie car $\Omega_{F/C}$ est un F-module et $D^1$ une dérivation sur $\Omega_{F/C}$ donc $ker(D^1) \subset \Omega_{F/C}$ donc $fw \in \Omega_{F/C}$.
\begin{proof}
Par l'absurde supposons qu'il existe $w_1,...,w_m \in \cap_{D \in \Delta} ker(D^1)$ et $f_1,...,f_m \in F$ non tous nuls tels que 
\begin{center}
$(*)$ ~~~~ $\displaystyle \sum\limits^m_{i=1}f_iw_i =0 $.      
\end{center}
On peut supposer que $m$ est la longueur minimale d'une telle relation et que $f_1=1$, on montrera que $\forall i, ~f_i \in C$. On peut alors appliquer $D^1$ pour $D \in \Delta$ à $(*)$, ce qui nous donne
\begin{center}
$0 = \sum\limits^m_{i=1} D(f_i)w_i+f_iD^1(w_i) = \sum\limits^m_{i=2} D(f_i)w_i$.
\end{center}
Par minimalité de la longueur de la relation on doit avoir $D(f_i)=0, ~\forall D \in \Delta$, c'est-à-dire $f_i \in C,~\forall i$. Cela permet de conclure. En effet, on a
\begin{center}
$\displaystyle \sum\limits^m_{i=1} f_i \otimes_C w_i =  \sum\limits^m_{i=1} 1 \otimes_C f_i w_i = 1 \otimes_C  \sum\limits^m_{i=1} f_i w_i = 0 $.
\end{center}
\end{proof}



\newpage
\nocite{*}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mabiblio}
\end{document}
```

My version of your incomplete bibtex file (more informative labels would be better, but they should be unique):

```
@Article{Ax,
author = {James Ax},
title = {On Schanuel's Conjectures},
journal = {Annals of Mathematics},
year = {1971},
volume = {93},
pages = {252-268},
}

@Book{NN,
title = {Corps commutatifs et thoérie de Galois},
publisher = {Calvage \& Mounet},
year = {2008},
}

@Book{AC,
title = {Algèbre corporelle},
chapter = {6},
publisher = {},
year = {},
pages = {139-164},
}
@Book{AG,
title = {Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves},
publisher = {},
year = {},
}

@Book{NN2,
title = {Introduction to commutative algebra},
chapter = {2},
publisher = {},
year = {},
}
@Book{CA,
title = {Commutative Algebra},
chapter = {26},
publisher = {},
year = {},
}
```

Comment: I tried as you say and still this error of capacity exceeded

Comment: Are you using pdflatex?

Comment: Yes i'm using pdflatex.